# count number of orders per user & Calculate average value per order per user

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID = c(1,2,3,1,1,3,2,4,5,5),    
orderDate = c("1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12", "1.1.12","1.1.12","2.1.12","2.1.12","2.1.12"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
itemPrice = c(9.99, 14.99, 9.99, 19.99, 29.99, 4.99, 9.99, 14.99, 49.99, 19.99))
```

Expected outcome:

```
NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2) 
AverageValuePerOrder = c(64.975, 19.985, 14.98, 64.975, 64.975, 14.98, 19.985, 19.985, 64.975, 64.975)
```

For Understanding:

The orderID is continuou. Products orderd from the same customer(ID) at the same day get the same orderID. When the same customer orders products at another day he/she it´s a new orderID.

Hi,

I want 2 thinks:
1. count the number of orders per user
2. Calculate the average value per order per user

How can we do this?

I tried it already with this:

```
DB$NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser <- with(DB,ave(as.numeric(mydata$orderDate), customerID, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
DB$NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser <- as.integer(DB$NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser)
DB$orderDate <- as.factor(DB$orderDate)
```

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: customer 1 orders on the 1.1.2012 (3products) and on the 2.1.2012 (2products) ->so the result should be 2 orders; customer 2 also ordered on 1.1.2012 (2products) and on 2.1.2012 (1product) -> so the result should be 2 orders; customer 3 orders only on 1.1.2012 (2products) -> so the result should be 1 order

Comment: how do you get average value of 64??

Comment: I added the item prices per order (for customer 1 order 1: 9.99+19.99 29.99=59,97; for customer 1 oder 2: 49.99 + 19.99= 69.98) and divide the sum (for customer 1 59.97+69.98=129.95) by the numer of order (for customer 1 (numberof orders of customer 1=2): 129.95/2=62.975)

Comment: Did anyone get a an idea why my solution  above (for counting the number of orders per user) is wrong?

Comment: Do the solutions work for you?

Comment: I try Hans Ekbrand solution at the moment - But it takes a long time because of the table size (about 500,000 lines-forgot to mention this at the beginning:sorry for that! ): is there a way which needs less performance then the ansers below? And yes:  I really need to transfer the summary data back

Comment: I´m not ignoring you Sotos: but I can´t check if your solution is working, because Hans solution is still in progress...

Comment: Hans was running for about 25Minutes: so I try yours now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, of course, many ways to do this. In your prefered outcome, there is redundant data. When you work with R, there is really no need to force the summary data back on to the individual records, instead you create a new object and continue the work with that object.

```
my.summaries <- data.frame(customerID = unique(DB$customerID),
                           NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser = sapply(unique(DB$customerID), function(customer) { length(unique(DB$orderDate[which(DB$customerID == customer)])) } ),
                           AverageValuePerOrder = tapply(tapply(DB$itemPrice, DB$orderID, sum), DB$customerID[match(unique(DB$orderID), DB$orderID)], mean)
                           )

my.summaries
  customerID NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser AverageValuePerOrder
1          1                            2               64.975
2          2                            2               19.985
3          3                            1               14.980
```

Should you really need to force the summary data back on to the individual records, use `merge()`

```
merge(DB, my.summaries)
   customerID orderID orderDate itemID itemPrice NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser AverageValuePerOrder
1           1       1    1.1.12      2      9.99                            2               64.975
2           1       5    2.1.12      5     19.99                            2               64.975
3           1       1    1.1.12      5     19.99                            2               64.975
4           1       1    1.1.12     12     29.99                            2               64.975
5           1       5    2.1.12      1     49.99                            2               64.975
6           2       2    1.1.12      2      9.99                            2               19.985
7           2       2    1.1.12      3     14.99                            2               19.985
8           2       4    2.1.12      3     14.99                            2               19.985
9           3       3    1.1.12      2      9.99                            1               14.980
10          3       3    1.1.12      4      4.99                            1               14.980
```

EDIT: since the original poster added a requirement that the solution should be fast, here is a fast solution, using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(DB)
orders.per.customer <- dt[, sum(itemPrice), by="orderID,customerID"]
my.summaries <- merge(orders.per.customer[, length(orderID), by=customerID],
                      orders.per.customer[, mean(V1), by=customerID],
                      by = "customerID")
colnames(my.summaries) <- c("customerID",
                          "NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser", "AverageValuePerOrder")
dt <- merge(dt, my.summaries, by = "customerID")
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got a problem: the original data is very big so that I need the solution which needs a minimum Computing performance: is there´s a way which needs less performance?

Comment: If the original data is very big, then all the more reasons not to force back the summaries on to the individual records.

In general, use the package `data.table` when dealing with Big Data. `data.table` provides ways to do summaries.

Comment: To have an idea- there are about 500.000 columns: your code is still running :/

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can solve it with data.table?

Comment: Sure, I have update the answer, and added a fast solution based on `data.table`.

Comment: the data table solution is not working: here´s the error:    Error in colnames(my.summaries) <- c("customerID", "NumberofOrdersOfSpecificUser",  : 
  object 'my.summaries' not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126107/discussion-between-hans-ekbrand-and-absolutebeginner).

Comment: Works pretty good - and fast :) But there is one more thing: when there are missing values (NA´s) or 0 entrys in column itemPrice there the AverageValuePerOrder is also NA: how can I solve it?

Comment: Add `na.rm=TRUE` as an argument to `mean()`, eg:

`mean(V1, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: If you find that the answer provides the solution, then please indicate that by accepting the answer.